# How do I import my WordPress comments into Disqus?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I installed the [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) plugin for my WordPress blog. How can I import my old comments into the plugin?

Comment: Looks like this is what you need: - http://disqus.com/comments/wordpress/

Comment: The below link provide you detailed information about how exactly you can import your old WordPress comments to Disqus plugin: [Exporting comments from WordPress to Disqus](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466255-exporting-comments-from-wordpress-to-disqus)